# Вопрос по клиент-северному приложению. Вопрос объясните. Как правильно реализовать?

Tags: tor

Требуется написать клиент-северное(чат) приложение, которое будет отправлять отчет на сервер(web-сайт). Но сайт этот находиться в сети TOR т.е. доменная зона .onion
Так захотел заказчик, черт. Ну, а у меня теперь вопрос. Мне получается нужно указать ссылку на этот сайт который находится в .onion в коде тупо. Он имеет вид: uhR3r3fdksguhe4rterwtre.onion. Или требуется подключаться с начало клиент-серверному положению(чату) к TOR и потом уж отправлять этот отчет в uhR3r3fdksguhe4rterwtre.onion в файл bagreport.log

P.S. Впервые пишу. По этому гуру прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: А вы пробовали взять ip адрес, а не домен? По сути .onion - это обычное доменное имя, за которым скрывается сервер самого сайта. К примеру вот вам `http://172.217.17.131` гугл, перейдя по адресу вы попадете на сайт самого гугла.

Comment: Я не знаю всех тонкостей TOR сетей. Попробуйте подключится к TOR, далее просто через cmd отправить пинг запрос `ping site.onion` и дальше смотрите что пишет, должен выдать адрес. Можете попробовать трассировку сделать (команда `tracert site.onion`), она выведет все узлы до конечной цели.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сеть tor не позволяет по именам определять ip-адреса, иначе бы анонимность пропадала

Comment: @Mike Возможно вы и правы, да. Ну тогда вариант тут по сути один - использовать прокси тора. У него вроде как есть возможность поднятия локальной SOCKS5 прокси, надо вроде только поднять сервер и подключаться через него. Скорей всего есть и готовые прокси с тором на борту, не знаю. Но явно стоит копать в сторону проксей.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, и кроме того даже для обычного HTTP обращение по доменному имени это **совсем** не то же самое, что подключение по IP-адресу... а в остальном идея верная — использовать любой HTTP(S)-клиент с поддержкой SOCKS5.

Comment: @ammstaff, не совсем понял... если кратко, то запускаешь tor-клиент (вручную или из своего приложения, не забывая указать настройки) → он поднимает проксю → далее любым http-клиентом (libcurl?) делаешь запрос на сервер в соответствии с его API. [Вот](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/jFyvepyjrCtSIWI8uhJO/) примитивный примерчик работы на `С/linux/libcurl`; [пример вывода](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/56Xp1pF39WislCltA7aF/). Само собой желательно предусмотреть возможность изменения настроек/использование внешнего tor-клиента для пользователя...

Comment: @ammstaff, «браузер tor» и не нужен — нужен только клиент, который предоставляет proxy-морду... в виде отдельной разделяемой библиотеки реализации такового пока нет AFAIK.

Comment: @ammstaff, на вид вроде тоже просто программа, но я бы не стал использовать что-либо класса «proof-of-concept» для чего-либо окромя ознакомления...

Comment: @ammstaff, это не бредовая, но не очень хорошая идея — трафик получаемый клиентом в таком случае не является анонимным... а сервисов таких разбросано много... все разной степени работоспособности на сегодня... гуглить по «tor web gateway» [первая ссылка](https://www.tor2web.org/), [вопрос на tor.se](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/what-are-the-best-tor2web-anonymous-gateways)

Comment: сервер остаётся анонимным. трафик внутри сети tor имеет сквозное луковое шифрование на уровне канала, а после выходных узлов — открыто (если не завёрнуто в tls). До web-гейтов он идёт или открыто или по tls, но оные так или иначе могут всё просматривать...

Comment: @ammstaff, по идее да — https должен идти только до их домена и сертификат выписан на него.... можно шифровать что-либо внутри http, например сами файлы, но протокол передачи остаётся открытым для шлюза...

Comment: @ammstaff, на сколько я понимаю их принцип работы — да... про безопасность — понятно, что абсолютной безопасности не бывает, но я бы сказал, что криптография достаточно надёжна, а как показывает история в основном органы находят злоумышленников по сторонним каналам, а не прямой атакой на протокол... но если это не **действительно** плохие вещи, то вряд ли кто-то будет связываться... **надёжно** полностью отключить/заблокировать доступ — почти невозможно; только если драконовскими мерами — заблокировать весь ssl-трафик... осложнить доступ — возможно и более простыми средствами...

Comment: @ammstaff, само собой уязвимости в реализации могут быть — чего один heartbleed стоил... у мвд, в моём представлении, вряд ли есть подобные возможности... у фсб/анб/гугла — может быть... они же смогут слить инфу кому-надо по необходимости... к тому же всегда можно криво настроить веб-сервер, чтобы он прямым текстом выдавал ip, домашний адрес и скан паспорта в теле страницы на 404-ю ошибку... тогда даже сельский участковый сможет отыскать, кому отправляются логи с отчётом об ошибке...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, всё, можете удалить. записал.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, вам нужен TOR-клиент. TOR-клиент предоставляет вам SOCKS-прокси, через который можно, в том числе, подключаться к скрытым сервисам в зоне onion.

Подключиться к этому прокси можно, к примеру, с помощью библиотеки [SocksSharp](https://github.com/extremecodetv/SocksSharp):

```
var settings = new ProxySettings()
{
    Host = "127.0.0.1",
    Port = 9050
};

using (var proxyClientHandler = new ProxyClientHandler<Socks5>(settings))
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(proxyClientHandler))
{
    var content = new StreamContent(...);
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://example.onion/", content);
    // ...
}
```